# Installing EF to .NET core library project

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, .net-core

I am new to .NET core. Trying to get used to it. But its kind of complicated.

I have my poco classes in *'solution.Entity'* library project and I want to use them to create a database with EF code first in my *'solution.Data'* library project.

But when I try to install Entity Framework via Nuget to my *'solution.Data'* project it says **'Package Restore Failed. Rolling back...'**

Both projects are **.NET Core Library projects.**

What do I need to do to be able to use EF in .NET core library projects? It's look like I need some kind of configuration.

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're installing `EF Core`. `.NET Core` has it's own implementation of Entity Framework.

[This should be the NuGet package you're installing.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/)

Comment: Okay it got installed. So what now? 

Can I not just right click the project and add EF code first now? or this method completely change?

Comment: It works exactly like regular EF (with some quirks, IIRC). So just do what you would do with normal EF.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of pieces to getting Entity Framework Core working right. I highly recommend taking a look at the docs. There are dozens of samples that show how to setup a project.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs

http://learn.microsoft.com/ef/

In particular, I suggest [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite).  It will talk you how to take your POCO classes and make a database in a .NET Core project. You will likely find it easiest to keep.everything in one project for now and move code into separate libraries once you get more familiar with EF.